# Genetic algorithm libraries for time series analysis/forecasting?

Tags: time-series, genetic-algorithm, forecasting

I am very interested in experimenting with genetic algorithms for prediction of market time series data.

I made my own rudimentary software, but it is clunky and inefficient.

Can someone recommend a free/open source library for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GAUL. It has libraries for lots of evolutionary algorithms, Simulated Annealling etc